# IsNull AMPscript function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Does the IsNull AMPscript function actually work?

I'm trying to figure out a scenario where it will actually return `true`. Here's what I've tried:

#### Test 1

```
%%[
var @rows
set @rows = LookupRows("July member promo","Member",1) /* returns 0 rows */
]%%

%%=IsNull(@rows)=%%
```

#### Result 1

`False`

#### Test 2

```
%%[ var @rows ]%%

%%=IsNull(@rows)=%%
```

#### Result 2

`False`

#### Test 3

**Surely** this must work as AttributeValue will return `null` if the attribute does not exist...

```
%%[
var @field
set @field = AttributeValue("a field that does not exist")
]%%

%%=IsNull(@field)=%%
```

#### Result 3

`False`

### IsNull versus Empty

And while I'm on the topic, if this function does actually return a correct result, then what's the difference between it and the Empty function? The Empty function returns to `True` if the expression is null or empty:

```
%%[
var @field
set @field = AttributeValue("a field that does not exist")
]%%

%%=Empty(@field)=%%
```

Comment: I was going to say that it may be used to detect the condition when a variable is not defined, yet referenced.  That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

The [IsNull](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/isnull.htm) AMPscript function only works with Data Extension fields, where if the field does not contain a value, then the function will evaluate to `True`.

For example, In the example below, there is no value for the "First Name" Data Extension field.

```
%%[
var @field
set @field = Lookup("Test DE","First Name","ID","ABC123")
]%%

%%=IsNull(@field)=%%
```

The function will return `True` if the field, irrespective of its type (text, number, boolean, date, etc), does not contain a value.